# Grassmannian $G(m,n)$ is locally Euclidean of dimension $m(n-m)$

Tags: general-topology, grassmannian

A generalization of projective spaces are the Grassmann manifolds. Consider $G(m,n)$ as the set of all $m$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The topology on $G(m,n)$ should then arise analogously to the topology of the projective space: the space $\text{Mat}(m \times n, \mathbb{R})$ carries the Euclidean topology. Let $X$ be the subset of $m \times n$ matrices of rank $n$. Then the topology of $G(m,n)$ is the final topology of $f: X \rightarrow G(m,n)$ with $f(A) = \text{im}(A)$, where $\text{im}(A)$ is the image of $A$, that is, the subspace spanned by the columns of $A$.

I would like to know how to show that $G(m,n)$ is locally Euclidean of dimension $m(n-m)$? The dimension is something I read in a more advanced book on differentiable manifolds.

Comment: Indeed, the (oriented) Grassmanian is the homogeneous space $SO(m+n)/S(O(m)\times O(n))$, which means it has dimension $\binom{m+n}{2}-[\binom{m}{2}+\binom{n}{2}]=mn$. (I think you are mixing up conventions when you say the dimension is $m(n-m)$; that's the dimension of the Grassmanian collecting the $m$-dimensional subspace of $n$-dimensional space.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for a comment, but maybe not a full answer either...)

Let $M\in X$,
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
v_1^1 & \cdots & v_1^n \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ v_m^1 & \cdots & v_m^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since the matrix is full rank by definition of $X$, there exist indices $I=\{i_1,...,i_m\}$, with
$$
1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_m\leq n,
$$
such that the $m\times m$ square matrix $M_I$ obtained from $M$ retaining only the rows with indices $i_1,...,i_m$ is invertible.

The matrix $\widetilde M:=(M_I)^{-1}M$ satisfies $f(M)=f(\widetilde M)$. The matrix $\widetilde M$ moreover has only $m(n-m)$ "nontrivial" entries (the submatrix $\widetilde M_I$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix).

The game to play now would be to show that:

1. the locus in $G(m,n)$ where $\det M_I\not =0$ is open (for any choice of indices $I$),
2. on this locus the coordinates given by the $m(n-m)$ nontrivial entries of $\widetilde M_I$ provide a local homeomorphism with $\mathbb R^{m(n-m)}$, and
3. changes of coordinates are smooth.

Comment: I think 3. is not necessary for my exercise, as this would prove the smooth manifold structure. I just need the local homeomorphism. Thank you, maybe I can manage to elaborate this! :-) If I can, I will credit you of course the full answer.